# How can Xcode add devices to developer portal with only a Member account?

Tags: xcode6, code-signing, provisioning-profile, udid

I just realized, despite only using the weakest member account, that Xcode has been adding device UDIDs to dev portal behind the scenes. Now if we login manually on the dev portal, we do not have access to addition of UDIDs. Why can Xcode do it?

At this point all I need to do, as a member, is to connect a device to Xcode and let Xcode fix things needed for a direct cable install, and the UDID of the device ends up on dev portal, no questions asked.

Comment: Re: when you say `weakest member account`, what does that mean exactly, is it a non-paying account?

Comment: No it is a **Member** account (as one of **Team Agent**, **Admin** and **Member**). Check out the list of available roles at https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/ In the grid it explicitly lists Member as not able to add UDIDs.

Comment: Interesting; are you sure there's no agent or admin account logged in? It's possible they've changed it or it's a bug. I know there have been some recent changes such as being allowed in install a built project on a device with v7 beta — so it might be related.

Comment: For this organization I do have a distribution certificate, but no other account above Member.

Comment: That said I do have an admin account as well, but that's a completely unrelated organization.

Comment: To be correct, the account is the same (same email), just a different, unrelated *team*. This account is an admin of our inhouse team, and a member of a client's team. Maybe the dev portal mixed some things up? Still I feel there is a possibility of a sane reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Xcode 7 I believe, developers who have a "member" role can add UDIDs.

See the table in this reference guide from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

I know this is a bit late coming, but it may help people in the future who experience the same.